# New MacBook Pro Discreet Graphics

Tags: graphics-card, macbook-pro-retina

I don't do video editing or gaming. Is a discreet graphics card going to help me if I work in Photoshop mainly and like a snappy computer above all else.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of work that you do in Photoshop and what version of Photoshop you use. However, this wasn't introduced until Photoshop CS4. Not all functions in Photoshop will be accelerated with your GPU.

A good forum post to read regarding GPU Acceleration in Photoshop. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/979969

**[About GPU and OpenGL](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/gpu-opengl-support-photoshop-cs4.html)**

Photoshop CS5 and CS4 leverage the video adapter's chip (the graphics processing unit, or GPU) instead of the computer's main chip (CPU) to speed some functions. Photoshop and Photoshop Extended access and use the GPU when the GPU:

- supports OpenGL, a software and hardware standard that accelerates video processing when working with large or complex images, including 3D.
- has at least 256 MB of RAM.
- has a display driver that supports OpenGL
  2.0 and Shader Model 3.0, which the GPU uses to perform rendering effects.

If your system meets the requirements, Photoshop turns on the Enable OpenGL Drawing preferences setting automatically on Mac OS, Windows, Vista, and Windows 7. In Windows XP (32 bit), you can turn on the option manually if your video adapter supports it.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. The new MacBooks only have discreet graphics at the highest spec machine. $600 more than the lower version, I'm struggling to see the justification in going for the high end model.